# Accessing data of one DBCS to another DBCS

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have two `DBCS` instance. `DB1` and `DB2`. I want to access data of `DB2` instance in `DB1`. 
I dont want to copy the `data` , I just want to access for reporting purpose.

Can you please help me on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within DB1, create a db link to DB2:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK "DB2"
   CONNECT TO "db2user" IDENTIFIED BY "db2userpwd"
   USING 'DB2';
```

Create a tnsnames.ora entry (in the tnsnames.ora of the DB1 machine) for DB2

Then when you want to select the data,

```
select * from my_db2_table@DB2;
```

Read more on DB Links in the SQL Reference.[create database link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5006.htm#SQLRF01205)

BTW, in the CREATE statement above, the two strings 'DB2' do not *have* to be the same, but probably should be for consistency.  The first (CREATE DATABASE LINK DB2) is the *name* of the *link* and is what is referenced in the sample SELECT statement. The second (using 'DB2') is the reference to the tnsnames.ora entry.

Comment: Thank you EdStevens. The above answer will definetly work for on premise database. But will it work for cloud databaae...DBCS?

Comment: As far as the network is configured to let the traffic go through between the two DBCS instances it should work. So basically you have to setup security list rule and if they are not in the same subnet, you might need additional gateway and route table rule.

Comment: Will it work for a cloud database?  As @isarecz stated, as long as the underlying, fundamental networking (apart from tns) is configured to allow the traffic, it shouldn't make any difference.  The TNS layer is totally dependent on the underlying OS networking. This link explains the relationship bet. TNS and the standard OSI network stack.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/network.112/e10836/layers.htm